# cookbook causing exception when running

Tags: chef-infra, graphite

Anyone have any luck installing graphite cookbook?
I have tried opscode community one and also latest heavywater one but no luck
e.g. heavywater gives the following exception when I try running it:

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound: resource template[/opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf] is configured to notify resource runit_service[carbon-cache] with action restart, but runit_service[carbon-cache] cannot be found in the resource collection. template[/opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf] is defined in /root/monitoring/cookbooks/graphite/recipes/carbon_cache.rb:28:in `from_file'
```

Comment: Did you try other Graphite cookbooks? Shameless self-plug: https://github.com/cmur2/chef-graphite - I wrote my own for more flexible configuration and understanding.

Comment: Cmur2 I am hoping to use the community cookbook. This wil ensure maintainability for me when the community cookbook gets updated

Comment: Good reason, could you give more details about e.g. which graphite related node properties you are using etc and a more complete error message with stack trace plz?

Comment: Updated question with relevant exception details

Comment: Are you using *runit* to manage your OS services? At least [the cookbook](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/graphite/blob/master/recipes/carbon_cache.rb#L20) assumes this and does not find runit afterwards - maybe you should change `node['graphite']['carbon']['service_type']` to reflect your preferences.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't have carbon-cache.py in the default location `/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was using the wrong cookbook version.

Needed to use an older version of the runit cookbook that was available at the time the graphite cookbook version was created.

I was using the latest version of runit that had moved on.

Don't know how people manage cookbook versioning, but I would have thought the appropriate versions of the dependent cookbook would be specified